# Why is MySQL returning rows not matching the ID?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table (set up for testing purposes) with just an `id bigint(20) auto_increment` column and 2 rows.

Now, if I try `select * from abc where id = '1'`, it works fine obviously, but any of these will also return the same row:

- `select * from abc where id = '1d'`
- `select * from abc where id = '0001blah'`

What's the deal? Does it have something to do with quotes? I always thought `=` meant it would return only the exactly matching rows...

Comment: *"I always thought = meant it would return only the exactly matching rows..."* Yeah, it does in its own interpretation of "matching" ;)

Comment: That's the way character to integer (actually, floating point) conversion works in MySQL. This is why you don't want to compare integers (numbers in general) with strings.